# Implementation of discrete Fourier Transform in Matrix Form

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

I am trying to gain an in depth understanding of how discrete fourier transforms work, and consequently I am trying to implement the discrete fourier transform myself in the form of a matrix.

First we initialize some parameters

```
n = 100; (* number of points *)
sr = 10;(* sample rate *)
dt = 1/sr; (* time increment *)
df = sr/nn; (* frequency Increment *)
f1 = 2;
p = 1/f1;
a = 5;
```

Generate a Periodic Data set where we know the frequency `f1`

```
data = Table[N[{t, a Cos[2 Pi f1 t]}], {t, 0, dt (nn - 1), dt}];
```

Perform the DFT as implemented in Mathematica and generate a frequency axis

```
ft = Fourier[data[[All, 2]], FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
freqs = Table[(n - 1) sr/nn, {n, nn}];
ListPlot[Transpose[{freqs, Abs[ft]}], PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, All}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: mathematica DFT]

Now Try to implement as a matrix equation by first calculating the matrix W

```
w = Table[
   N@Exp[ (-I 2 Pi j k)/nn], 
   {j, 0, dt (nn - 1), dt}, 
   {k, 0, dt (nn - 1), dt}];
```

Multipy the data vector and the matrix W, and plot the absolute value

```
discretefourier = Transpose[{freqs, Abs[dt (w.data[[All, 2]])]}];
ListPlot[discretefourier, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, All}]
```

[image: Wrong Answer]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have defined your w matrix incorrectly -- it should be all integer j and k (and independent of dt).

```
w = Table[N@Exp[(-I 2 Pi j k)/nn], {j, 0, (nn - 1)}, {k, 0, (nn - 1)}];
```

You can make this equal to the built in FourierMatrix by changing the sign and scaling properly:

```
w = Table[N@Exp[(I 2 Pi j k)/nn], {j, 0, (nn - 1)}, {k, 0, (nn - 1)}];
FourierMatrix[nn] == w/Sqrt[nn]
True
```

(Thanks to Jens for the pointer).

Comment: See also `FourierMatrix`...